Twins, identify the liar, find out their identity

Arthur and Robert are identical twins. One is a knave and he always lies. The other is a knight and always tells the truth, but you don’t know which one is which.
One day you meet one of them and want to find out whether it’s Arthur or Robert. But you can ask only one yes/no question, and the question can’t contain more than three words. What question will do? Alternatively, suppose you want to find out whether it’s Arthur or Robert who’s truthful. What three-word yes/no question will reveal the answer?


I already know the answer to the question. I have posted this here to ask how one should go about solving this question. Is it just trial and error?  Basically, is there a good logical way to approach this question( using a truth table or something of that form)?

If there wasn't a three word limit to the questions we can ask, then what other questions will give us the answers that we seek?


Source: From Raymond Smullyan’s 2009 book Logical Labyrinths. Also mentioned in Jason Rosenhouse’s book, Games for Your Mind, 2020.

To find out if you met Arthur, ask

 Is Arthur truthful?
 Yes answer: You met Arthur the knight or Arthur the knave so you met Arthur.
 No answer: You met Robert the knight or Robert the knave so you met Robert.

To find out if Arthur is truthful, ask

 Are you Arthur?
 Yes answer: You met Arthur the knight or Robert the knave so Arthur is the knight.
 No answer: You met Arthur the knave or Robert the knight so Arthur is the knave.


Thanks for answering. But I am more interested in knowing what can be a logical way of approaching this question. Or if trial and error is the only way of solving this question.

You want a question so that it will be answered with yes if  is true and answered with no if  is false.

I wouldn't call it logical exactly, but notice the "trick" - to find out who you met, you don't ask who you met. To find out who is truthful you don't ask who is truthful. This is because you don't know if it's a lie or not. You construct a different question that will get a yes or no (whether that's true or false) based on what you want to figure out.
